# Formatter Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception, formatter

I'm getting errors with this code that I don't understand. I have everything set up in accordance with the Java documentation, but clearly I'm not understanding something. First, here is the code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class CreateTextFile {

    private Formatter output; //object used to output text to file

    public void openFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            output = new Formatter( "sets.txt" ) {    //First Error

                @Override
                public String format(LogRecord record) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                }


            }; //open the file
        } catch ( SecurityException securityException ) {
            System.err.println("You do not have access to this file.");
            System.exit(1); //terminate the program
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {  //second error

        }
    }
}
```

First Error:

> constructor Formatter in class Formatter cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: no arguments
>     found: String
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I understand the error message, but I don't agree with it. There is definitely a constructor for Formatter that takes a single string (see below)

Second Error:

> constructor Formatter in class Formatter cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: no arguments
>     found: String
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I'm throwing the FileNotFoundException in the method declaration just as described in the Java documentation below.

This is straight from [http://doc.java.sun.com/DocWeb/api/java.util.Formatter][1]

> Formatter(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException Constructs a
>   new formatter with the specified file name.
>
> The charset used is the default charset for this instance of the Java virtual machine.
>
> The locale used is the default locale for this instance of the Java
>   virtual machine.
>
> fileName  The name of the file to use as the
>   destination of this formatter. If the file exists then it will be
>   truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created. The
>   output will be written to the file and is buffered.
>
> Throws    SecurityException: If a security manager is present and
>   checkWrite(fileName) denies write access to the file
>
> Throws    FileNotFoundException: If the given file name does not denote
>   an existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of that name
>   cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while opening or
>   creating the file

Not sure how to clear these errors. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
```

In the URL of the Javadoc you are quoting:

```
java.util.Formatter
```

It's not the same class.

Comment: Ack! My capacity for stupid mistakes knows no bounds. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the documentation of java.util.Formatter, but you are importing java.util.logging.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I didn't see that.